# Java ArrayList converted to C++

Tags: java, c++, arrays, porting

I have an ArrayList

```
ArrayList[][] gridList = new ArrayList[300][150];
// Where a and b are some values in the range of the ArrayList.
ArrayList al = this.gridList[a][b];
```

How could this be translated to C++ ??
I've tried using std::vector or std::map, std::array.
I just can't get it to work.

```
ArrayList al = this.gridList[a][b];
```

What does that line actually do?

Does it create an array of size ??

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList[a][b]
```

or maybe it copies the values of "a" and "b" in to the new ArrayList "al" ?

Please help

Comment: Please try and keep your posts to one question - are you asking how to translate an `ArrayList` to C++, or what `ArrayList al = this.gridList[a][b];` does?

Comment: @PhilipKendall OP wants to know how to translate a two dimension array of Java `ArrayList` class to C++.

Comment: You don't have an array list. You have an array of arrays of ArrayList. i.e. you have 300 * 150 references to ArrayList (all being null). a and b are allow getting one of these refereces, the one at the coordinates a, b in the matrix of ArrayLists. new ArrayList[a][b] creates a new array (of length a) or arrays (of length b) of ArrayList.

Comment: Sorry for asking too many questions at once. As mentioned below my question is how to translate the part ArrayList al = this.gridList[a][b] into C++?   I can see later in the Java code that "al" is used in a loop like this (Integer)al.get(i)).intValue();

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does.

```
 ArrayList[][] gridList = new ArrayList[300][150];
```

This first line allocates an `array` of `array` of `ArrayList`.

```
 ArrayList al = this.gridList[a][b];
```

This second line retrieves the `ArrayList` at offset `b` in the `array` at offset `a` in the `array` gridList. *You should be aware that your code doesn't initialize either arrays*.

The equivalent type in C++ could be:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

std::array< std::array< std::vector<T>, 150>, 300> gridList;
```

where `T` is the type of the element stored in the vectors. Note that Java prior to generics only allowed to define ArrayList without specifying the element type, which is pretty much what your code does. In C++, this parameter is mandatory. The above variable definition will instantiate it for the current scope. you will need to use a `new` statement for a dynamic value (as in Java), and probably wrap it with a smart pointer.

To access an element of the grid, you can use the `[]` operator:

```
 vector v = gridList[a][b];
```

Beware that this will trigger a full copy of the `vector` content in the grid at position < a,b > into `v`. As suggested, a more efficient way would be to write:

```
auto const &al = gridList[a][b];
```

Again, the memory model used by Java is very dynamic, so if you want code closer in behaviour to the Java version, you would probably have something like:

```
 #include<memory>

 typedef std::vector<int> i_vector;
 typedef std::shared_ptr<i_vector> i_vector_ptr;
 typedef std::array< std::array< i_vector_ptr>, 150>, 300> vector_grid;

 typedef std::shared_ptr<vector_grid> vector_grid_ptr;

 vector_grid_ptr gridList;

 i_vector_ptr al = (*gridList)[a][b];
```

with type `T` being `int`, and each component of the grid type clearly defined.  You still have to allocate the grid and each element (ie. `i_vector` here).

Comment: How do you in your C++ example later retrieve array at offset a and offset b ?  that is the part I get lost in

Comment: @user1185305 `const auto& v = gridList[a][b]`. Bear in mind that here you need to know the dimensions (150 and 300) at compile time. You basically can't have a generic direct translation from java to c++. You have to specify clearly what you want.

Comment: yes, I assumed here that the dimensions are constant. Otherwise a more classic C-style array would be necessary (or vector).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work (if you need container class):

```
struct Item
{ ...
};

typedef std::vector<Item> ArrayList;

// Single row.
struct ArrayListVector : public std::vector<ArrayList>
{
    ArrayListVector() { resize(150); }
};

// Whole matrix
struct ArrayListMatrix : public std::vector<ArrayListVector>
{
   ArrayListMatrix() { resize(300); }
};

...

ArrayListMatrix gridList;  //< yes, it is 300 x 150
ArrayList &a = gridList[a][b]; //< or, you can make a copy
gridList[b][a] = a; //< assign an entry
```

Or do you need templates?

However there is a simple option, that doesn't need templates, classes, etc:

```
 ArrayList array[300][150]; //< array is allocated (on stack, or statically).
```

Comment: To be honest I don't know what I need. I just want to know how to translate those lines of Java code into C++ so that I can port the code.

Answer (score 1):

If your ArrayList is holding something of type 'Foo', then:

```
std::vector<Foo*> gridList[300][150];
std::vector al = this->gridList[a][b];
```

Comment: std::vector al = this->gridList[a][b];   Doesn't seem to compile. Any suggestions??

Comment: It compiles but I get SIGABRT when I run.

Comment: You need to specify the type that the vector holds - I used 'Foo' as an example.